# OSError: file not found

Tags: python, file-not-found

I'm trying to write a script that needs to rename (in the script itself, not in the folder) some `.txt` files to be able to use them in a loop, enumerating them.

I decided to use a dictionary, something like this:

```py
import os
import fnmatch

dsc = {}

for filename in os.listdir('./texto'):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(filename, 'dsc_hydra*.txt'):
        dsc[filename[:6]] = filename
        print(dsc)
print(dsc['dsc_hydra1'])
```

The 'print(something)' are just to check if everything is going well.

I need to rename them because I'm using them in future functions and I don't want to address them using all that path stuff, something like:

```py
IFOV = gi.IFOV_generic(gmatOUTsat1, matrixINPUTsat1, dsc['dsc_hydra1'], 'ifovfileMST.json', k_lim, height, width)
```

Using `dsc['dsc_hydra1']`, I get this error:

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mainSMART_MST.py", line 429, in <module>
    IFOV1= gi.IFOV_generic(gmatOUTsat1,matrixINPUTsat1,dsc['dsc_hydra1'],'ifovfileMST.jso',k_lim, height, width)
  File "/home/alumno/Escritorio/HDD_Nuevo/HO(PY)/src/generateIFOV.py", line 49, in IFOV_generic
    DCM11,DCM12,DCM13,DCM21,DCM22,DCM23,DCM31,DCM32,DCM33 = np.loadtxt(gmatDCM,unpack=True,skiprows = 2,dtype = float)
  File "/home/alumno/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 962, in loadtxt
    fh = np.lib._datasource.open(fname, 'rt', encoding=encoding)
  File "/home/alumno/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/_datasource.py", line 266, in open
    return ds.open(path, mode, encoding=encoding, newline=newline)
  File "/home/alumno/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/_datasource.py", line 624, in open
    raise IOError("%s not found." % path)
OSError: dsc_hydra1.txt not found.
```

I've already checked the folder and the file is there, why do I keep getting this error?

Comment: Do you prepend the folder path to the file name ? I see you are looping through `./texto` but then you don't try to open `./texto/dsc_hydra1.txt`

Answer (score -1):

I had this same issue. It cannot locate the `.txt` file because you're in the wrong directory. Make sure that where you're trying to execute the code is within the directories of which the code needs. Hope this helps.

Comment: Your answer is not comprehensive enough. Stating that the OP is executing the script from a wrong directory is too generic. Try to point out where the problem exactly lies and what the solution exactly is.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem. In my case, inside the file.txt, I had a space at the end of the string. You should control the spaces! For example, inside the file.txt (space = -):

```
-365-
string1-
string2
-string3
```

if you remove all the spaces (-) it should work!